# Is my Reasoning Correct? $\mathbb{Q}$ is not the countable intersection of open sets.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification

I know the question has been asked before, but I want to know if my reasoning makes sense. I've done the first part but am unsure about the second. It goes as follows:

1. Show that  $\mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Q}$ is not the countable union of closed sets.
2. Show that $\mathbb{Q}$ is not the countable intersection of open sets.

My question is: For the second part, using the first part of the problem, is it correct to say that
$$ (\mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Q}) \neq \bigcup_ {n\in\mathbb{N}} C_n \text{ , where $C_n$ is a closed set $\Rightarrow$ }$$
$$(\mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Q})^c \neq (\bigcup_ {n\in\mathbb{N} } C_n)^c  \text{ , where little c is the complement}\Rightarrow  $$
$$(\mathbb{Q}) \neq \bigcap_ {n\in\mathbb{N} } (C_n)^c =\bigcap_ {n\in\mathbb{N}} O_n \text{ , where $O_n$ is an open set} $$

Comment: Your formal use of the set theoretic constructs is correct, but your proof is missing all the words that I need to understand the reasoning. I think you should start with something like "I will prove (2) using (1), by contradiction. Suppose that $\mathbb{R} - \mathbb{Q}$ is a union ... of closed sets. Then ... (because ...) so (and so on)."

Comment: @EthanBolker For proof by contradiction, you'd want to go the other way, no? Suppose you have $\mathbb{Q}$ as an intersection of open sets; then the complement is a union of closed sets.

Comment: @ConnorHarris Yes, I got it backwards in my quick read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I follow what you have done, but I don't think the logic quite works. I think you successfully show that $Q$ is not the intersection of some specific open sets, $(C_n)^c$  formed from a specific choice of closed sets $C_n$.

The standard proof would be by contradiction starting from the other end......

Assume that $O_n$ is **any** countable collection of open sets with $Q = \cap O_n$
Then $ \mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q = \mathbb R \setminus \cap O_n  = \cup \mathbb  R \setminus O_n$
And it is the case that the complement of **any** open set is closed, so that with $C_n = R \setminus O_n$ then  $\mathbb  R \setminus \mathbb Q = \cup C_n$ would be the countable union of closed sets, which contradicts the first part.